# prohibit to move window with some title

Tags: c, winapi, hook

I need to prohibit window moving with some title.
// Hooks.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TCHAR s[50];
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HHOOK hHook;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
    return 1;
}

TCHAR s[50];
HHOOK hHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
//   HDC hdc;
if (nCode < 0)  
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

//  hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
CBT_CREATEWND* cbt=(CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam;
if (nCode==HCBT_MOVESIZE)
    if (!lstrcmp(s,cbt->lpcs->lpszName)) return 1; 
return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
return 0; 
}
```

but I've got an error when I move window. When I change its position It changes but then I've got error - access violation at adress 67471040 in module Hooks.dll(my dll).Read of adress 00000116

Comment: How are you initializing 's'? The hook DLL gets loaded into each process separately, so you can't just set 's' in the main process, you have to separately communicate the value to each DLL instance, perhaps using shared memory of some sort. My guess is that s here is uninitialized and that the error is happening in lstrcmp due to this.

Comment: This is the epitome of questions which will never help anyone else; voting to close as too localized. OP, you can solve this by just using a debugger.

Comment: If you think `s` is the problem, why not declare and initialize it inside the actual Hook callback and see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `lParam` into a pointer to `CBT_CREATEWND`, but that is only so if `nCode==HCBT_CREATEWND`, and that is obviously not the case. When `nCode==HCBT_MOVESIZE` then lParam points to a `RECT` struct.

You should process first the `HCBT_CREATEWND`, filter it and save the related HWND to make the condition when `HCBT_MOVESIZE` happens.
That won't work if the window changes the title, however.

BTW, can't you just call `GetWindowText()` to get the window title?